# A single method Accepting 3 arguments or 4 arguments

Tags: c#, methods

```
    public static void fillCheckList(string ListType,int RecordNum,CheckBox chkRequired,TextBox txtComplete,TextBox txtMemo)
    {
        string sql_Check = String.Format(@"SELECT l.Required,l.Completed,l.ISP,l.Memo_Notes,
                                            t.List_Desc
                                            FROM List_Data l, List_Type t
                                            WHERE l.List_ID = t.List_ID
                                            AND l.Record_Num = {0}
                                            AND t.List_Desc = '{1}'", RecordNum,ListType);
        ListData LIST = new ListData();
        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd_Check;
        SqlDataReader dr_Check;
        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString);
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd_Check = new SqlCommand(sql_Check, sqlConn);
            dr_Check = cmd_Check.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr_Check.Read())
            {
                LIST = new ListData(Convert.ToBoolean(dr_Check["Required"]), dr_Check["Completed"].IsNull() ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr_Check["Completed"]), dr_Check["Memo_Notes"].ToString());
            }
            chkRequired.Checked = LIST.REQUIRED;
            txtComplete.Text = LIST.COMPLETED.HasValue ? LIST.COMPLETED.Value.ToShortDateString() : "";
            txtMemo.Text = LIST.MEMO_NOTES;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error found in fillCheckList..." + Environment.NewLine + e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, i take in an integer variable for the project id, a string variable for list type, and 2 text box type.
i am thus using this method to accept 4 arguments.. what i want to do is that i also want it to accept 5 arguments . that is.. include one more text box..
so that it either takes 4 arguments or 5 arguments accordingly/
how do i do that in the same method.

Comment: Use SqlDataParameters!!!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  **You _need_ to use parameters.**

Comment: There's params in the answer too but these guys are talking about a different kind of params (which you may not know).

Change your sql string to use @RecordNum and @ListType instead of using {0} and {1}. Next, in the SqlCommand object, insert the params like so: cmd.Parameters.Add( "@RecordNum", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int ).Value = RecordNum;

Comment: You may want to use a using statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28VS.71%29.aspx) is your friend.

eg:

```
public static void fillCheckList(string ListType,int RecordNum,CheckBox chkRequired, params TextBox[] txtBoxes)
{
   TextBox txtComplete = null;
   TextBox txtMemo = null;
   TextBox txtThirdOne = null;

   if(txtBoxes.Length < 1)
   {
      throw new Exception("At least the txtComplete-Textbox has to be given");
   }
   else
   {
      txtComplete = txtBoxes[0];

      if(txtBoxes.Length >= 2)
          txtMemo = txtBoxes[1];

      if(txtBoxes.Length >= 3)
          txtThirdOne = txtBoxes[2];
   }

   // do stuff    
}
```

Comment: params is your worst nightmare... (in this case)

Answer (score 10):

**Do not use params for this.**

Use params to represent the idea "I can take zero, one, or *arbitrarily many* extra parameters. It sounds like you want to take zero or one extra parameters.

TJMonk15 is right; you should either use an optional parameter (in C# 4), or write two methods and have one of them call the other with a default value for the extra parameter. Preferably the latter.

(And for goodness sake fix that SQL injection vuln!)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using c# 4.0 you can use [Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(VS.100).aspx). If not, you should use method overloading and using one overload to call the other with a default value for the last parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Check the keyword [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, check it, but don't use it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use params but it requires either you to have a random number of arguments of the same type or having a loose typed collection of arguments (object)

You can also write your function with 5 arguments and provide an overloaded method with 4 arguments that calls the former and defaults the last parameter.

```
public static void fillCheckList(string ListType, int RecordNum, CheckBox chkRequired, TextBox txtComplete)
        {
            fillCheckList(ListType, RecordNum, chkRequired, txtComplete, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

1.

```
public static void fillCheckList(string ListType, int RecordNum, CheckBox chkRequired, TextBox txtComplete, TextBox txtMemo) {
     fillCheckList(ListType, RecordNum, chkRequired, txtComplete, txtMemo, null);
}
public static void fillCheckList(string ListType, int RecordNum, CheckBox chkRequired, TextBox txtComplete,TextBox txtMemo,TextBox txtMemo, TextBox txtMemo) {
     // implementation
}
```

2. public static void fillCheckList(string ListType, int RecordNum, CheckBox chkRequired, IEnumerable textBoxes) {
            // implementation
       }

3.

```
public static void fillCheckList(string ListType, int RecordNum, CheckBox chkRequired, params TextBox[] textBoxes) {
         // implementation
    }
```

Option 1. is ok if you need to add different members and you have a finite set of possibilities.

Option 2. is ok. But not a elegant as 3.

Option 3. is maybe the best thing to do, as long as the added parameters have a common ancestor - object if it must be. Remember that params alway has to be the last parameter.